# want to remove entity that has no label from the result

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'd like to ask one tricky thing about label. Using `SERVICE` keyword like `SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en". }` enable us to switch language label when the first preference is not mached to the target entity label.
However, I want to drop out some entities that does not have any label. However, the `service` keyword add entity with Qxxxx label when the entity does not have any language match label. How could I remove the entity from the result? 
I know we can filter that out using `rdfs:label` for the all the variables explicitly but setting all the rdfs:label to all the variables is another headeache. So I'd like to know how to improve the query with `SERVICE wikibase:label` I want to filter out entity that doesn't have any label. Should I replace `SERVICE` with `rdfs:label`?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?vLabel 
    WHERE { 
    hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?i {
            ?i wdt:P31 wd:Q515.
        }LIMIT 15
    }
        ?v wdt:P937 ?i.
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en". } 
    }
    LIMIT 3
```

```
RESULT:
Q59780594 <- no lang label
Q24642253 <- no lang label
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikidata label service doesn't provide a built-in way to skip resources that don't have a label.

The simplest option would be to wrap the query as a subquery into a new `SELECT` query, and use a filter to remove any `Qxxxx` labels. This uses the fact that only the real labels have a language tag:

```
SELECT ?vLabel {
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?vLabel
    ...
  }
  FILTER lang(?vLabel)
}
```

**Edit:** Below is my original (and inferior) answer, which used a regular expression on the label itself to remove the `Qxxxx` ones. It would also filter out any resources that *actually* have a label of the form `Qxxxx`, if such resources exist in Wikidata.

```
SELECT ?vLabel {
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?vLabel
    ...
  }
  FILTER (!REGEX(?vLabel, "^Q[0-9]+$"))
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `filter(lang(?vLabel)!='')` would be better.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Great suggestion! Or even just `FILTER lang(?vLabel)`, since empty strings are “falsy”. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Actually I like the regex one, because I found that the variable v can be url or some value that does not have ```label``` but valid for the answer. If I filter it out with ```FILTER LANG``` those values are also filtered out. The regex above purely filter out ```Qxxx``` stuff that I was originally intended to.